# faster extend 8-bit mask to 16-bit for MCU

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, assembly, algorithm, optimization

Using an 8-bit flag register, the goal is to generate a 16-bit mask for manipulating a 2-byte settings register where adjacent pairs of bits control a channel, e.g. writing `0x2 (0b10)` for channel 2 would be to take `0x04 (0b00000100)` from the flag register and generate `0x0030 (0b0000000000110000)` to be ANDed with a constant setting mask `0xAAAA (0b1010101010101010)`, resulting in `0x0020 (0b0000000000100000)`.

The equivalent digital logic "circuit" to generate the mask would look like this:

[image: 8to16]

One seemingly straightforward way of implementing this in software is to shift one bit out for every two in (i.e. serial approach), paying attention to endianness. In CPU12 assembly (big endian):

```
    LDX     #2     ;counter: 2 bytes
L1  LDY     #4     ;counter: 4 bits
    LDAA    flag   ;get flag register
L2  LSRA           ;shift lsb into carry
    PSHC           ;copy carry (ccr)
    LSRB           ;shift carry into msb
    PULC           ;paste carry
    LSRB           ;shift carry again
    DBNE    Y,L2   ;loops 4 times
    PSHB           ;store half-result (1 byte)
    DBNE    X,L1   ;loops 2 times
    PULD           ;retrieve resulting mask (2 bytes)
```

(1) Is there a faster algorithm for this procedure without resorting to wiring up 24 MCU pins as illustrated, or a lookup table; e.g. one that is able to process multiple bits concurrently? (2) Is there a name for this procedure?

Comment: The below answer seems good enough for you, keep in mind that the digital logic circuit <-> program analogy falls quite early, i.e. you can't make a single processor do things in parallel, not in the sense you're asking here. A LUT will work but would require 256*16 bits of memory, that can be a problem on smaller systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for are Morton numbers of `x` with `x`.

Various ways for computing Morton numbers: [Bit Twiddling hacks](http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN)

Specializing the binary magic numbers method for 8-bit input and 16 bit output (C-style code):

```
uint16_t x; // set lower 8 bits of x for input

x = (x | (x << 4)) & 0x0f0f;
x = (x | (x << 2)) & 0x3333;
x = (x | (x << 1)) & 0x5555;

uint16_t res = x | (x << 1); // could also store result in place
```

This handles any combination of input bits. Ex.: if `x = 0x5` (`0b101`), then `res = 0x33` (`0b110011`)